# Array of objects update logic not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

am new in programming. I am trying to update cart items. On instance of click "OK" in modal, the One_item object is updated. Then this object is passed on to Cart_Item array, which contains the total items.

I tried to write the logic in Listval() function in the Menu component. The One_Item  object is updated properly. But the if condition at the bottom of the Listval(), is adding , but not updating.

Please see the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-stallman-98o58

Relevant function to look into

```
Listval() {
    let ll = "$" + this.state.listvalue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

    let ll2 = this.state.listvalue.replace(/\d+/g, "");
    let ll3 = ll2.replace(/\$/g, "");

    let ll4 = ll.replace(/\$/g, "");
    let ll5 = this.state.Select_Quantity;
    let ll6 = parseFloat(ll4) * ll5;

    let ll7 = this.state.Total_Item || [];
    ll7.push(ll3);
    ll7 = [...new Set(ll7)];

    
    this.setState(
      {
        Select_Price: ll,
        Select_Item: ll3,
        Select_Item_TotalPrice: ll6,
        Total_Item: ll7
      },
      () => {
        // CHANGE: Use callback function to send data to the parent component
        this.props.updateTotalItems(this.state.Total_Item.length);
      }
    );

   
    // append  new object This is where problem starts, the new object pushes at second click

    

    if (this.state.Item !== this.state.Select_Item) {
      let xx = {
        Price: ll,
        Item: ll3,
        Quantity: this.state.Select_Quantity,
        Total_Item_Price: ll6
      };

      // const Cart_Item = Object.assign(xx, this.state.Cart_Item);
      let yy = this.state.Cart_Item || [];
      yy.push(xx);
      this.setState({ Cart_Item: yy });
    }

    //else try to update object based on property value
   // This is not working at all. it keeps on adding objects instead of updating
    else {
      for (var i in this.state.Cart_Item) {
        if (this.state.Cart_Item[i].value === this.state.Select_Item) {
          this.state.Cart_Item[i].Price = ll;
          this.state.Cart_Item[i].Item = ll3;
          this.state.Cart_Item[i].Quantity = this.state.Select_Quantity;
          this.state.Cart_Item[i].Total_Item_Price = ll6;
          // }

          break; //Stop this loop, we found it!
        }
      }

// i tried below logic as well but it didnt work
      //  this.setState({

      //   Cart_Item:this.state.Cart_Item.filter(v => v.this.state.Select_Item.includes(this.state.Item))
      //   .concat([ xx ])

      //  });
    }
    console.log(this.state.Cart_Item);
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend you try console logging at various points in your code, so you can see what you're actually getting at various points. And then you can reason backwards as to why you're getting different results than you expect. Often conditional logic doesn't work as expected because you're not actually comparing what you think you are. Could be because of comparing different data types or a variety of other issues.

Comment: What is `One_Item` object? Please also include steps to reproduce issue. On a previous question of yours I had to fix the modal OK button to get it to work correctly (this sandbox has same issue) and it still has other various react element attribute issues. It's obvious you're doing a state mutation, but without a working sandbox and reproduction steps it's difficult test.

Comment: Hi Drew. Thanks again to addressing my problem . I think the sandbox this time is up to date. So onClick of the Modal, it save One_Item object using Listval() in Menu component. Now in this same function, i like to add contents to the Cart_Item array containing objects. Each Item will be added in Cart_Item , which contains an object with key-value pairs. So now in the last past of Listval, i need to first check if the item is present or not, if not, then i push new object to the Cart_Item array, otherwise update it.